# Selecionar Cidade e Estado [Filtro]

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

Gostaria de criar duas `ListPicker` ou até mesmo um `LongListSelector`, para que quando o usuário selecionar um Estado "x", apareça as cidades em outra `ListPicker` ou entrasse em outra janela com mais um `LongListSelector`, as cidades que nesse estado existem franquias (que será resultado de um `webservice`) que no momento estou fazendo como um mockup.

Como proceder nisto? Já procurei em vários lugares..

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma mais simples será quando existe uma `selectionChanged` na primeira `listPicker` alterar a source da segunda `listpicker`.